# Playing the notes on the right side of piano with the left hand

Tags: piano, fingering

I'm currently learning the "Fur Elise" on the piano from youtube. In the tutorial, at [this](https://youtu.be/4rs4IYUoI1Y?si=j7WYlouXo7BDV69G&t=404) timestamp, the teacher plays some notes on the right side keys with her left hand, which seems unnecessary to me, as I think you can play only the two E notes on the left side with the left hand, and continue to play all the other notes with the right hand.

I wonder what the reason for this left hand pattern is, and why the notes on the right side aren't played with the right hand? It seems easier to play that way.